# How to show extends in Enterprise Architect

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I am pretty new at EA and am trying to show an extension of JFrame, much like in this picture:

http://msoe.us/taylor/se1021/lab5.png

In the Barnyard class, it has *JFrame* in the upper right corner. How do I accomplish that on my own class?
Just so you are aware, I do not own this original EA file so I cannot reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 2):

The notation with the name of another class in italics in the upper right corner is EA's way of showing a generalization (UML's name for inheritance, which in Java is called extension) when the class being inherited *from* is not in the same diagram. If they are in the same diagram, you get the regular triangular-arrowhead connector.

The normal way of creating a generalization is simply to drop the two classes on the same diagram and draw the connector between them. You can also select the child class (Barnyard) and press Ctrl-I to bring up a dialog that lets you select parents to be inherited from (and interfaces being implemented).

However you make the connection, EA will automatically show the connector if the two classes are on the same diagram, and display the inherited class(es) in the top right corner if they're not.